# ASP Classic Authorization Include File - Redirect Immediately or use If..Else

Tags: asp-classic

This is probably a simple question, but I can't think of the best answer.

In a Classic ASP Site, I do authorization with an if/then statement like this:

```
if session("isAdmin")=true then
' Page Body
else
    Response.Redirect to Session/Auth Expired
end if
```

I wondered if it would be the same to do this instead:

```
if not session("isAdmin")=true then
    Response.redirect to Session/Auth Expire
end if
' Page Body
```

Should I wrap the page in an if..then or can i just include a file at the top that checks and redirects before the page body appears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second option works fine. The user will be redirected before the rest of the page body is processed/rendered.

Comment: While true some details would be useful e.g. link to official documentation proving this.